# Is there a way to add a ppa using the python apt module?

Tags: python, ubuntu, debian, apt

I need to add a ppa to remote servers using a python script. The bash equivalent of what I want to do is:

```
$ add-apt-repository ppa:user/ppa-name
```

I'm assuming it would look something like this:

```
import apt
cache = apt.Cache()
# ?? add the ppa here ??
cache.update()
cache.open(None)
cache['package_from_ppa'].mark_install()
cache.upgrade()
cache.commit()
```

but I haven't been able to find much in the apt module source related to adding repositories.

Comment: Try asking on http://serverfault.com/  They should be able to help!  Good Luck! :)

Comment: add-apt-repository is a python script :)

Comment: Here's the [source](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~ubuntu-core-dev/software-properties/main/view/head:/add-apt-repository)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

taken from the current (in 11.04 natty) add-apt-repository code:

```
from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties
sp = SoftwareProperties()
sp.add_source_from_line(ppa_name)
sp.sourceslist.save()
```

You should of cause add checks for errors, etc... 
look at the currently installed version like this:

```
less `which add-apt-repository`
```

Answer (score 0):

I noticed op never got the answer he wanted so here is the solution.

```
import aptsources.sourceslist as s
repo = ('deb', 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/danielrichter2007/grub-customizer/ubuntu', 'xenial', ['main'])
sources = s.SourcesList()
sources.add(repo)
sources.save()
```